# Sectional page count with flying saucer and css

Tags: java, html, css, pdf, flying-saucer

I am using *flying saucer* for generating PDF report from a web HTML.
My report contains multiple sections and each section may or may not occupy multiple pages in the report

My requirement is to show section page count in the *Header*

```
-----------HEADER-----------
     My Fancy Report
     First Section (Page 1)
-----------------------------
.
. First Section (conitinued)
.
-----------HEADER-----------
     My Fancy Report
     First Section (Page 2)
-----------------------------
.
. First Section (Completed)
.
 -----------HEADER-----------
     My Fancy Report
     Second Section (Page 1)
-----------------------------
.
. Second Section 
.
```

---

I tried using a counter like below

```
header { counter-increment: myCounter; }
header:after{content: ' (Page ' counter(myCounter) ')' ;}
#page{ counter-reset: myCounter; }
```

*#page is an element which occurs on every start of new section*

Doing this, I never see counter is reset with new section.

Seems like the *counter-reset* doesn't work with flying-saucer, that's what I read somewhere.

Can anyone let me know, what is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `counter-reset` doesn't work correctly with Flying-sacuer, I found a simple workaround. Hope this will help others

As mentioned in my question I have multiple running Headers (sectional headers) in my document. I create a separate counter for each of the sectional header and increment them independently.

```
#sectionOneHeader{ counter-increment: sectionOneCounter; }
#sectionOneHeader:after{ content: ' (Page ' counter(sectionOneCounter) ') '; }

#sectionTwoHeader{ counter-increment: sectionTwoCounter; }
#sectionTwoHeader:after{ content: ' (Page ' counter(sectionTwoCounter) ') '; }
```

and this worked exactly the way I wanted.